# WCF Data Services | How to handle nullable property with nested properties?

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

When I have changed BarCodeId FK to allows null in ContactDocument. After that I start get errors in client if any entities in ContactDocument has null BarCodeId. If I remove the last three expands all will be work, but I will not get entities related to BarCode object. Any Help?

```
IQueryable<ScanDocument> result = Context.CreateQuery<ScanDocument>("DocumnetsWithNotRemovedContacts")
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ScanDocumentPropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.BarCodePropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "/" + Contact.ContactDocumentsPropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.ScanDocumentDetailPropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "/" + Contact.ContactSourcePropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "/" + Contact.ElectionDistrictPropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "/" + Contact.ContactTypePropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "/" + Contact.ContactSalutationPropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "/" + Contact.ContactGroupsPropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "/" + Contact.CategoryInterestsPropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.BarCodePropertyName + "/" + BarCode.ContactDocumentsPropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.BarCodePropertyName + "/" + BarCode.BarCodeActionTypePropertyName)
        .Expand(ScanDocument.ScanDocumentDetailsPropertyName + "/" + ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "/" + ContactDocument.BarCodePropertyName + "/" + BarCode.ScanDataTypePropertyName)
        .OrderByDescending(document => document.ID);
```

on the server side I started to use something like this to get nested properties.

```
CurrentDataSource.ScanDocumentDetails
             .Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ScanDocumentPropertyName)
             .Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName)
             .Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.BarCodePropertyName)
             .Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "." + Contact.ContactDocumentsPropertyName)
             .Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.ScanDocumentDetailPropertyName)
             .Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "." + Contact.ContactSourcePropertyName)
             .Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "." + Contact.ElectionDistrictPropertyName)
             .Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "." + Contact.ContactTypePropertyName)
             .Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "." + Contact.ContactSalutationPropertyName)
             .Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "." + Contact.ContactGroupsPropertyName)
             .Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.ContactPropertyName + "." + Contact.CategoryInterestsPropertyName)
            //.Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.BarCodePropertyName + "." + BarCode.ContactDocumentsPropertyName)
            //.Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.BarCodePropertyName + "." + BarCode.BarCodeActionTypePropertyName)
            //.Include(ScanDocumentDetail.ContactDocumentsPropertyName + "." + ContactDocument.BarCodePropertyName + "." + BarCode.ScanDataTypePropertyName)
            .Where(c => ids.Contains(c.ScanDocumentID ?? 0)).ToList();

        foreach (var scanDocumentDetail in y)
        {
            foreach (var contactdocuments in scanDocumentDetail.ContactDocuments)
            {
                if (contactdocuments.BarCode != null)
                {
                    int barCodeActionTypeId = contactdocuments.BarCode.BarCodeActionTypeId;
                    contactdocuments.BarCode.BarCodeActionType =
                        CurrentDataSource.BarCodeActionTypes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == barCodeActionTypeId);

                    if (contactdocuments.BarCode.ScanDataTypeID.HasValue)
                    {
                        int scanDataTypeId = contactdocuments.BarCode.ScanDataTypeID.Value;
                        contactdocuments.BarCode.ScanDataType =
                            CurrentDataSource.ScanDataTypes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == scanDataTypeId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**UPD**
exception:
"Error processing response stream. Server failed with following message:\r\nAn error occurred while processing this request."
Source:System.Data.Services.Client
Status Code:500

StackTrace:

```
at System.Data.Services.Client.Xml.XmlAtomErrorReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlSubtreeReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.ReadElementFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomParser.XElementBuilderCallback(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomParser.ParseCurrentEntry(AtomEntry& targetEntry)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomParser.Read()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.Read()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNextInternal()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ClientDataServices.MailProcessingManagmentService.GetDocuments(Expression`1 filter) in D:\...\MailProcessingManagmentService.cs:line 41
   at ClientDataServices.MailProcessingManager.GetEntries(Expression`1 predicate) in D:\...\MailProcessingManager.cs:line 24
   at MailProcessingModule.ViewModels.MailProcessingViewModel.RefreshEntityHandler() in D:\...\MailProcessingViewModel.cs:line 113
   at BaseModule.BaseGridViewModel`1.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<ListEntities>b__d(Object e) in D:\...\BaseGridViewModel.cs:line 178
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Answer (score 0):

WCF Data Services has a server side limit on the number of expansions allowed. I think it's 14, so your query above will probably fail.

If you would place post the exact error message you get it might help to confirm the root cause of the problem.

Expanding properties which are null should work just fine, there won't be any results but that's to be expected.

Comment: Can you please follow the description here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx to enable verbose error messages (don't forget to turn them of for production) and post the error message you get. Alternatively, attach a debugger to the service and let it stop on all exceptions. The error will be thrown as an exception which would be interesting to see.